# How to get Key of selected Observable Collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

I have an observable collection with KeyValuePair. I need to get the key of the selected item.

```
 private ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<String, Items>> _items;


 <ListView Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedThings, Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectedValuePath="Value" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Image Height="40" Source="Resources/Apps64.png"/>
                            <TextBlock MinWidth="120" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Key, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: can't remember out the top of my head, but try using WPF inspector. It will help you hunt down solutions like this.

Comment: Do you want the key to be available in the viewmodel or in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `Items` collections is something like this :

```
private ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string,string>> _items = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string,string>> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_items == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _items = value;                
        }
    }
```

then to get the `SelectedItem` Key from your viewModel, simply create a `KeyValuePaire` property in your view model and bind it to your `ListView`'s `SelectedItem`

```
private KeyValuePair<string,string> _selectedItem  ;
    public KeyValuePair<string,string> SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItem;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_selectedItem.Equals(value))
            {
                return;
            }

            _selectedItem = value; 

        }
    }
```

and to get the Key of the `selectedItem` in your Xaml simply use `ElementName` `Binding` to the `ListView`'s `SelectedItem` :

```
 <ListView x:Name="Lv" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedThings, Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectedValuePath="Value" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Image Height="40" Source="Resources/Apps64.png"/>
                    <TextBlock MinWidth="120" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ElementName=Lv,Path=SelectedItem.Key}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```